# How do I get AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID for Amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, access-keys

I'm totally new to AWS.

I downloaded some sample code from Amazon and I need to set a number of constants:

- `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`
- `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`
- `MERCHANT_ID`
- `MARKETPLACE_ID`

I just created an AWS account. I want some type of sandbox account so I can try out the code samples.

What are the exact steps I have to take to:

1. Create a sandbox account
2. Get these credentials

Answer (score 274, accepted):

1. Go to: http://aws.amazon.com/
2. Sign Up & create a new account (they'll give you the option for 1 year trial or similar)
3. Go to your [AWS account overview](https://console.aws.amazon.com)
4. Account menu in the upper-right (has your name on it)
5. sub-menu: Security Credentials

Comment: Thanks for that Amit but I did that. However I don't want to send actual payments, etc. I wanted to mock all those transactions. That's why I wanted to get the sandbox. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: AWS is pretty much for the first year. If you pick up 't1.micro' EC2 is does not cost you anything. all startups usually use it in the begging. you can start & stop your servers anytime you like via aws website and if something has a cost, you pay only on the actual usage.

Comment: @AmitTalmor Also, agreed that most startups use it while *begging*

Comment: These are old instructions. See [Jace Browning's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37947853/3129414)

Answer (score 116):

1. Open the [AWS Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com)
2. Click on your username near the top right and select **Security Credentials**
3. Click on **Users** in the sidebar
4. Click on your username
5. Click on the **Security Credentials** tab
6. Click **Create Access Key**
7. Click **Show User Security Credentials**

Comment: There is no security credentials option when clicking my username in the navbar.

Comment: @SgtPooki it's called **My Security Credentials** :)

Comment: I do not see `My security credentials` when clicking on my username on the top right corner. All I see are `Account`, `Organization`, `Service Quotas`, `Billing Dashboard`, `Switch Role`, `Signout`.

Comment: This is outdated like every other post about AWS that is older than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 59):

Amazon changes the admin console from time to time, hence the previous answers above are irrelevant in 2020.

The way to get the secret access key (Oct.2020) is:

1. go to IAM console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam
2. click on "Users". (see image)
   [image]
3. go to the user you need his access key.
   [image]

As i see the answers above, I can assume my answer will become irrelevant in a year max :-)

HTH

Answer (score 35):

Amit's answer tells you how to get your `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, but the **Your Security Credentials** page won't reveal your `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.  As [this blog points out](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1R9KDN9ISZ0HF/Where-s-my-secret-access-key):

> Secret access keys are, as the name implies, secrets, like your
>   password. Just as AWS doesn’t reveal your password back to you if you
>   forgot it (you’d have to set a new password), the new security
>   credentials page does not allowing retrieval of a secret access key
>   after its initial creation.  You should securely store your secret
>   access keys as a security best practice, but you can always generate
>   new access keys at any time.

So if you don't remember your `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, the blog goes on to tell how to create a new one:

1. Create a new access key:

[image]

2. "Download the .csv key file, which contains the access key ID and secret access key.":

[image]

As for your other questions:

- I'm not sure about `MERCHANT_ID` and `MARKETPLACE_ID`.
- I believe your sandbox question was addressed by Amit's point that you can play with AWS for a year without paying.

Comment: just a heads up, you can now view your keys without downloading them through the webpage

Answer (score 14):

It is very dangerous to create an access_key_id in "My Account ==> Security Credentials". Because the key has all authority.
Please create "IAM" user and attach only some policies you need.

Comment: This is not an answer to OPs question. There are cases where you need this.

Comment: It is a good point, but Sean256 is exactly correct, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

To find the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY Its better to create new  create "IAM" user
Here is the steps https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html
1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/.

2. In the navigation pane, choose Users and then choose Add user.

Answer (score 3):

suppose by any chance you have already configured your local aws cli earlier.  
now you need access-key-id and secret-access-key for any reason. 
its saved in credentials folder of aws. 
in  macos 
`cd ~` 
`ls -a` 
`cd .aws` 
`ls` 
`open credentials`

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new access key, you will get an option to copy and to download the `AWS secret access key` at step 3. Once you click `Done` button, I don't think you can copy the secret access key afterwards. You might have to delete that one and create new one to get secret key.

The .csv file will have both `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

[image]