# What is aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've signed up for a new AWS account and generated a new keypair.  I've got the PEM file.

I start a new instance and log into it.  I'm trying to do an 'aws configure' but its asking for aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key.  What are these?  I've just got this PEM file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get AWS\_ACCESS\_KEY\_ID in amazon? Sandbox account of some kind?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440709/how-do-i-get-aws-access-key-id-in-amazon-sandbox-account-of-some-kind)

Answer (score 15):

[AWS Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-security-credentials.html)

> When you interact with AWS, you use AWS security credentials to verify who you are and whether you have permission to access the resources that you are requesting. In other words, security credentials are used to authenticate and authorize calls that you make to AWS.

[Types of Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html)

> Access keys (access key ID and secret access key)
>
> Access keys consist of an access key ID (like AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE) and a secret access key (like wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY). You use access keys to sign programmatic requests that you make to AWS whether you're using the AWS SDK, REST, or Query APIs.... Access keys are also used with command line interfaces (CLIs).

Finally, under [How Do I Get Security Credentials?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/getting-aws-sec-creds.html)

> Access keys (access key ID and secret access key)
> ... You can create new access keys for the account by going to the [Security Credentials](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential) page. In the **Access Keys** section, click **Create New Access Key**.

Comment: Everyone links to this page, but it has no "Access Keys" section. I think this answer might be out of date.

Comment: For me, the section is instead called "Create individual IAM users". This indicates it might also be about the type of account I'm using. But be aware that this answer doesn't apply to everyone.

Comment: the second link ("types of") has 'access keys', @rspeer.

Comment: I was referring to the actual Security Credentials page, not the documentation. When it says "In the Access Keys section, click Create New Access Key.", it presumes you have an Access Keys section.

Comment: @rspeer you can't click on that "security credential" link as a root user?

Comment: No, I'm not a root user. If you're presuming the user is a root user, you should say so.